# convert nested json to csv using node.js

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I want to convert a nested json to csv file using node.js.
my JSON structure:

```
[
{
    "Make": "Nissan",
    "Model": "Murano",
    "Year": "2013",
    "Specifications": {
        "Mileage": "7106",
        "Trim": "SAWD"
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "flavor": {
                "name": "Cherry",
                "id": 1
            },
            "packSize": {
                "name": "200ML",
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "flavor": {
                "name": "Vanilla",
                "id": 2
            },
            "packSize": {
                "name": "300ML",
                "id": 2
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Make": "BMW",
    "Model": "X5",
    "Year": "2014",
    "Specifications": {
        "Mileage": "3287",
        "Trim": "M"
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "flavor": {
                "name": "Cherry",
                "id": 1
            },
            "packSize": {
                "name": "200ML",
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "flavor": {
                "name": "Vanilla",
                "id": 2
            },
            "packSize": {
                "name": "300ML",
                "id": 2
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I have used 'json-2-csv' module but it only converts the simple structure not the nested structure.
only the 'make','model','year' and 'specification' is converted,'items' are not converted
How to do this???

Answer (score 7):

You can use the module `jsonexport` its pretty easy, check this sample:

**Here is the output using the json you provided and jsonexport:**
[image]

**Sample:**

```
var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

var contacts = [{
   name: 'Bob',
   lastname: 'Smith',
   family: {
       name: 'Peter',
       type: 'Father'
   }
},{
   name: 'James',
   lastname: 'David',
   family:{
       name: 'Julie',
       type: 'Mother'
   }
},{
   name: 'Robert',
   lastname: 'Miller',
   family: null,
   location: [1231,3214,4214]
},{
   name: 'David',
   lastname: 'Martin',
   nickname: 'dmartin'
}];

jsonexport(contacts,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
});
```

**The ouput:**

```
lastname;name;family.type;family.name;nickname;location
Smith;Bob;Father;Peter;;
David;James;Mother;Julie;;
Miller;Robert;;;;1231,3214,4214
Martin;David;;;dmartin;
```

**Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport**

Comment: for the json value, i've mentioned earlier,it's not working properly.Please try with that json array and mention a proper solution.

Comment: I just tested with jsonexport and i got this output, is that what you was expecting ?`Items.packSize.id,Items.packSize.name,Items.flavor.id,Items.flavor.name,Specifications.Trim,Specifications.Mileage,Year,Model,Make
1,200ML,1,Cherry,SAWD,7106,2013,Murano,Nissan
2,300ML,2,Vanilla,,,,,
1,200ML,1,Cherry,M,3287,2014,X5,BMW
2,300ML,2,Vanilla,,,,,`

Comment: No,Where are the values of make,model and year.The output has some blank value.

Comment: @Subham I included a picture in my answer so you will be able to understand what the CSV means and where are the model and year fields.

Comment: @Subham I hope its clear now that `jsonexport` is able to handle the json you provided =)

Comment: It looks like the library has a fillGaps option that will prevent missing data.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport documentation.

Comment: This jsonexport module works great for converting nested JSON to CSV!

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have the same numbers of columns ?
 ie : Do you have a fixed (or max number) of items ?

```
Make;Model;Year;Mileage;Trim;Item_1_flavor_name;Item_1_packSize_name;Item_2_flavor_name;Item_2_packSize_name
```